# List of publications in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

Is there any table or any way to see a list of the backoffice publications in Umbraco?

I need to know all the publications done of the lasts days, including the date of each publication.

I know in the Umbraco DB there is the table ContentXml, but it only has the last update date of each node.

I need to see something like:

***Node -------- Date ------------- User***

11 //   11-10-2013:10:08:10 // admin

16 //   11-10-2013:12:08:10 // admin

...

Comment: Would this also require each version published? Also, which version of Umbraco are you using?

Comment: I'm using the 4.9.0. If possible I'd like to know each version published. Do you know if that exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cmsDocument table holds a list of nodes ids with version numbers, with the update date. DocumentUser should be the user who published the content, which you can grab from the umbracoUser table.